# <arg> tag in launch-files

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

the wiki-pages aren't that precise. Is it right, that the arg tag can be used within an include tag and within a launch tag, but not within anything else? So it can't exist in a group-tag?

Kind regards,
Filip

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11209/%3Carg%3E-tag-in-launch-files/) by [Filip](https://answers.ros.org/users/633/filip/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-09-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the  tag inside of , , and .  I have updated the wiki docs.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `<arg>` XML tag syntax is sometimes confusing. Note that it can be either a *declaration* or an *assignment*.

- To *declare* an `<arg>`, put it almost anywhere in the file before using the `$(arg)` substitution variable.
- To *assign* a value, nest it within the `<include>` tag, or pass it to the top launch file via a parameter to `roslaunch`.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-09-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Filip](https://answers.ros.org/users/633/filip/) on 2011-09-14**:
And  is like . ;)

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-09-14**:
Not sure, hence the vague answer. It can certainly go within the scope of the `<launch>` tag.

**Comment by [Filip](https://answers.ros.org/users/633/filip/) on 2011-09-14**:
What means almost anywhere?